# webdriver+IE9 : weird shake effect

Tags: internet-explorer-9, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I see a weird behavior when i run my script in IE9 
I have a main page with a few icons/links that redirect me to my applications !
The point is that , when main page opens , the mouse cursor "shakes" between these link (very fast ) for 10 sec more or less. 
After that , it clicks the correct link!
Any idea why this happens? 
It's just on IE, ff,chrome are fine !

Answer (score 1):

Jim Evans has written a blog post on this describing what is happening:

http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/revisiting-native-events-in-ie-driver.html

To get around it I would suggest using the REQUIRE_WINDOW_FOCUS capability:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
capabilities.setCapability(REQUIRE_WINDOW_FOCUS, true);
capabilities.setCapability(LOG_LEVEL, "FATAL");
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);
```

You should see no more flickering and a marked improvement in anything hover related.

Comment: In that case you could set it as the correct answer and/or give me a +1 :)